# How to encode FLAC with seek points using FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I simply encode FLAC file using this command:
`$ ffmpeg -i test.webm -codec:a flac output.flac`

The result `output.flac` doesn't contain `SEEKTABLE` metadata. In [FLAC document encoding options](https://xiph.org/flac/documentation_tools_flac.html#flac_options_seekpoint), it has `--seekpoint=#` option to `"specific sample number for a seek point"` but FFmpeg doesn't has similar option for FLAC encoder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. FFmpeg has no provision for this. Feel free to create a ticket as an enhancement at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Ticket is here it would seem: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6978